# Acceleration in relativistic particle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, relativity

Suppose that a relativistic particle of mass at rest $m_0$ and charge $q$ moves under the influence $F$. Show that the acceleration $a$ of the particle can be expressed as follows:

$$a = \frac1mF + \frac{v}{mc^2}(Fv)$$

Where $v$ and $m$ are the velocity and mass of the particle.

I can´t figure out how they get the second term of the sum, can any one help me?

Answer (score 2):

It's done like this:

The movement equation is $\frac{d p}{d t} = F$, where $p=m_0 \gamma v$, since $\gamma \equiv (1-(\frac{v}{c})^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ and $ a \equiv \frac{d v}{d t} $ you just have to input the expression of $\gamma$ in the first equation and you'll get:

$$F= m_0 c \frac{d}{d t} \left[ \frac{(v/c)}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}} \right] = m_0 \frac{1}{\left(1-(v/c)^2\right)^{3/2}} \frac{d v}{d t} = m_0 \gamma \frac{1}{1-(v/c)^2} \frac{d v}{d t} \rightarrow $$

$$\rightarrow a=\frac{F}{m_0 \gamma} \left( 1-(v/c)^2\right) $$

Defining the mass as $m\equiv m_0 \gamma$ you get the result.

I hope that this was useful!

Comment: This is great!!, I just can't see how you go from $c \frac{d}{d t} \left[ \frac{(v/c)}{\sqrt{1-(v/c)^2}} \right]$ to $\frac{1}{1-(v/c)^2} \frac{d v}{d t}$, how do you get it?

Comment: Just make the derivative, check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule

Comment: And I made a little mistake, I will modify the post.

Comment: just applied chain rule and the derivative rule, but don't get the same result

Answer (score 0):

It is done in Ladau-Lifshitz textbook, as a problem at the end of § 17.

Landau, L.D. and Lifshitz, E.M, The Classical Theory of Fields,
Vol. 2 (4th ed.), Reed Educational and Professional Publishing Ltd,
1975, Problem to §17, p. 52.

Comment: This doesn't help OP if he doesn't have the book.

Comment: @0celo7: Indeed.